# Knockout-validation not working well on IE8

Tags: knockout-validation

When I use my website using IE8, the validation is not working well because it is failing on the next function inside knockout.validation.debug.js. If I use the website with Chrome, FF or IE9, everything works fine.

The Error that is showing:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'hasOwnProperty'


values: function (o) {
            var r = [];
            for (var i in o) {
                if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    r.push(o[i]);
                }
            }
            return r;
        },
```

I also tried to replace o.hasOwnProperty(i) with Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,i), but this is not working either. Any idea how to make it work with IE8?

Comment: I have been having the same issues. I have a client that still uses IE8 internally, all of the code works great for newer browsers but not for their internal users. Apparently this project has been abandoned, which is incredibly frustrating because there really is NO alternative for KnockoutJS validation, and and I do not want to waste my time writing plugins for a framework that seems to be getting abandoned as well (knockoutjs). If you did eventually come up with a solution to this I would love to hear it.